# ¿Como puedo descargar enlaces de forma directa?

Tags: php, html, html5

Buenas mi pregunta escomo puedo descargar de forma directa este tipo de enlaces:

https://ia800301.us.archive.org/0/items/electricsheep-flock-244-32500-3/00244%3D32593%3D23650%3D23640.mp4

Sin tener que darle clic derechi y descargar.

Comment: En HTML5 puedes usar el atributo `download`, algo así: **`<a href="https://ia800301.us.archive.org/0/items/electricsheep-flock-244-32500-3/00244%3D32593%3D23650%3D23640.mp4" download="el-nombre-que-quieras.mp4">Descargar mp4</a>`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés hacerlo con PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
$file = "URL";

// Quick check to verify that the file exists
if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");

// Force the download
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");

readfile($file);
```

Comment: ese es el codigo que busco

Comment: pero me da error en la línea 5

Comment: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="" . basename($file) . """);

Comment: Cuál es el error que te figura?

Comment: Ya corregí las comillas y ahora no debería dar ningún error.

Comment: Gracias, un saludo

Comment: y sabrías decirme como seria para enlaces externos a mi web?